# SQL Server 2017 monitor and alert of stored procedure duration while it is still running

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2017 CU6 Enterprise. Is there a way to monitor and alert on running stored procedures on specific database if more than - say two minutes - has passed - but, while it is still running. I know multiple resources exist to capture that after it was done - e.g. xEvents, QueryStore, ..  - but I need to capture that while stored procedure is still running and then write to eventlog or sending email with powershell or else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would use Adam Mechanic's [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/).

This well documented procedure is a go-to in the community to see what is running on your server. By default, it doesn't return sleeping SPIDs.

To capture the results, [check out this part of the documentation](http://whoisactive.com/docs/25_capturing/).

You will also want to limit it to a specific database or host or whatever. [For that, Check out deciding what not to see.](http://whoisactive.com/docs/09_deciding/)

You can find all of the help by running `sp_WhoIsActive @help = 1` or just reading the full docs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - Yes, I know about WhoIsActive , but this is tracking duration on the session level - not SP level and in my case, one single session/connection can keep sending multiple SPs and queries.

Comment: So you care more about the cumulative running of a proc? So your session will execute the same proc over and over?

Comment: Yes - or multiple SPs and queries with different parameters

Comment: In that case, have you thought about using `dm_exec_requests` paired with `dm_exec_sql_text`?

Comment: I did  - but will review this again if that can provide the conditions I'm looking for.

Comment: Not yet  .. got dragged to other production stuff  ..  but will get to it for sure. Thanks!